# Связь таблицы sql (user - profile)

Tags: php, mysql

Как правильно делать связи таблиц и создавать автоматически строку во второй таблице с `id` первой таблицы.

К примеру, как при создании нового пользователя в таблицу `user` создавалось автоматически строка в таблице `profile` и в поле `user_id` создавалось `id` нового `юзера`?

Я нашел некоторые примеры, но не совсем пойму как правильно их использовать.

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD CONSTRAINT fkey
FOREIGN KEY (P_Idq)
REFERENCES Personstable(P_Idq)
```

Comment: foreign key только создает ограничение, контролирующее, что в подчиненной таблице не может быть записей с id не существующими в основной. С помощью простых правил такого рода невозможно сделать, что бы запись создавалась автоматически. Вам следует написать триггер на вставку в таблицу пользователей, который будет сам давать insert в таблицу profile. что то вроде этого https://habrahabr.ru/post/37693/

Comment: *К примеру, как при создании нового пользователя в таблицу user создавалось автоматически строка в таблице profile и в поле user_id создавалось id нового юзера?* Описанная ситуация (вернее, НЕОБХОДИМОСТЬ наличия записи во второй таблице) приводит к мысли о связи 1:1. Что в свою очередь порождает вопрос о целесообразности деления на две таблицы.

Comment: да то что нужно, спасибо большое, по поводу второй таблицы user и profil как пример был

Comment: @Akina, целесообразность? а как же **академический интерес**? разве этого мало?)